# create dynamic manyToOne and OneToMany entity in correct way

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a question about how to correct way to implement a good way for creating oneToMany and ManyToOne entity with hibernate

and I have promotion entity, that entity has column *code* and *discount* and *category_id*

I have a category  also but those categories have some child ( subcategory, EX: category for `GREEN` is for *cat* and *dog*, and for `BLUE` is for *cow*, *bird*, and *pig*)

for the table, it would like this for me

```
table ===>  category
column: name, sub_category ,promotion_id 

table ====> promotion 
column: code, discount, category_id
```

is my entity diagram is bad or need to be add something or edited?

on my entity domain:

I create a category like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category extends Base {

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "name")
    private Set<Category> categories;

    @ManyToOne
    private Promotion promotion;

}
```

and

for promotion, I create to like this

```
@Entity
@Data
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "PROMOTION")
public class Promotion extends Base {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="promotion")
    private Set<Category> categories;

    @Column(name = "CODE", unique = true)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "DISCOUNT", nullable = false)
    private Integer typeDiscount;
}
```

`Base` here is something entity for id, createdAt, deletedAt,

so my question here, is my entity for relationships correct?
if no, what should I should revision?

i am very new for Java here

Comment: `@ManyToMany` with join table can be clean solution for your mapping

Comment: will u give me example ? it would be good to see the example one, because i am pretty new for this @emotionlessbananas

Comment: try this: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: i still figure it out, not get any illustrations yet for me question now, because i have subcategories @emotionlessbananas

Comment: in that case you need to show your schema design,